# In English can you say something like: To feel addressed?

Tags: translation

I am puzzling how to translate an expression in Dutch to English. There is a way of saying something in German and Dutch that is literally translated to: Do you feel (as) spoken to? For example you complain about people proselyting their point of view on politics or religion, on a website that is intentionally about information exchange. Then somebody gets mad, and you want to say something like: When you get this mad about is, you probably feel offended, you probably do the same, you feel as we were speaking about you. How can I express that?

Comment: [If the shoe fits](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-the-shoe-fits.html)...

Comment: I know exactly the notion you're thinking of. I'm certain it exists in Danish as well (though for the moment, I cannot think of it). The closest equivalent I can think of in English, though, is something like, “Touched a nerve, eh?”, which is similar, but not _quite_ the same idea.

Comment: NL: Voel je je <wat>? DK: føler du dig truffet

Comment: @oerkelens, that one is close, too, but still not quite right. “If the shoe fits” requires a comment/context more directly aimed at the speaker than the Dutch/Danish expression. Imagine a girl says, “Some guys just have no idea how girls want to be treated”, and a guy friend then says, “Well, it's not our fault! You girls are always giving mixed signals, and then suddenly changing your mind and getting morose or angry for no good reason; you're impossible to figure out!”. -->

Comment: --> The girl might then use the expression in this question. Here, “Ooh, touched a nerve, did I?” could work, but really the idea is “Well, I wasn't necessarily even talking about you, you know… but it looks like you're guilty of it, by your words!”

Comment: @mplungjan, Yes! _Truffet/ramt_, that's what it is.

Comment: You are a typical case in point yourself?

Comment: Being Danish I know the Danish version, being non-native Dutch speaker, I cannot think of the Dutch version - aangesproken?

Comment: @mplungjan yes, _voel je je aangesproken_ is the Dutch version :)

Comment: Yes, 'touched a nerve', or 'the shoe fits' are too directly. It's really like, by getting that angry, you expose the fact you are probably guilty of it. Hard one, right?

Comment: *take offense*? *umbrage*?

Comment: you can say "you feel as you were the **target/target audience/addressee**."

Answer (score 2):

**Are your ears burning?** is pretty close.

It comes from the old legend that you could tell if someone was discussing you out of earshot by the ears getting warm.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of an exact phrase but there are a handful of related or similar sayings in English. The easiest is simply "talking about you":

> Oh, we weren't talking about you.

This is often expressed after a generalizing statement in order to exclude present company:

> Men are boys. Oh! We weren't talking about *you*, Bob.

This primarily differs from your intended meaning in the sense that it is not asked of the *listener* but is a clarification from the *speaker*. You could say:

> Do you think we are talking about you?

But this is rather passive-aggressive and isn't extremely common.

Similar sayings:

- "Don't speak about me as if I'm not here!" — An objection that expresses the feeling you describe. This does not work as a question.
- "I resemble that remark!" — A tongue in cheek objection of the implication.
- present company excluded — Making an explicit exception for someone listening. This is often tongue in cheek.

But the most appropriate saying is "**hits close to home**":

> Ouch, that hits close to home.

This does have an associated question variant:

> Did that hit a little close to home?

The meaning conveyed here is that there is some personal context that may not have been immediately obvious. It can used when someone commits a faux pas by accidentally insulting or speaking about someone who is present.

> I don't understand how anyone can kill themselves. Don't they understand how selfish that is?
>
> *Bob starts crying.*
>
> Oh, sorry, did that hit too close to home?

This can be used in a context that is less severe but more intended to defuse any particular offensive:

> Ugh, I cannot stand people who voted for that candidate. They are destroying this country.
>
> Heh, that doesn't hit a little too close to home, does it Bob?

Both of these uses are *extremely* delicate and when the phrase is appropriate or not depends greatly on the specific social culture. It is most often used to refer to an event *after* the relevant person has left:

> Wow, I cannot believe Bob just started crying like that. Must have hit close to home...

Answer (score 1):

"A bit too close {to the mark / for comfort}, eh?"

Answer (score 0):

How about "Do you feel as if you were being alluded to?"

Comment: I like it. Is it a commonly used expression?

Comment: It's part of my idiolect...but better ask the others such as FumbleFingers about how common it is.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a _common expression_ as such. It's easily understood and quite clear, but it's not a set phrase or idiom like the Dutch. At least not that I know of.

Comment: I believe it accurately expresses what the  OP wanted to say ("...you feel as if we were speaking about you.")

Comment: Yes, but it is just not common because you can never completely translate such idioms 'one to one'. If it is not uncommon and understandable, I am happy with this as translation.

Comment: If someone can come up with a better one, which I doubt, I'll be glad myself.